# Sha'atnez and small children

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, mitzvah, shaatnez, baby-infant

I was sent an email today alerting my community that Sha'atnez has been discovered in a line of baby pants. A quick internet search turned up other baby clothing that has been discovered to have Sha'atnez.

My question: Am I supposed to care?  Put less bluntly, does the Isur Sha'atnez apply to babies?

Comment: How is this different from feeding them treif or break shabbat or etc.?

Comment: @DoubleAA, IINM, there is a Kabbalistic basis for not feeding children non-Kosher food, as it is spiritually harmful for them. As for Shabbath, there is a special injunction of "Atah UVincha". As for other Isurim, [see here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4858/5).

Comment: So isn't that last point your answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm hoping someone has something specific to Sha'atnez vis a vis children.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Minchas Chinuch 551:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37518&st=&pgnum=173) it is prohibited to put Shatnez on even an infant that has no Da'as.

Comment: It seems that he's not sure and leaves it as a matter of doubt.