# What are parents responsible for if the children can't sin?

Tags: bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

If a child under bar/bas mitzvah is not obligated in mitzvos, they should not be able to sin either (can't commit a sin by not-performing/violating something you weren't obligated to perform/refrain-from in the first place).

If so, what is the meaning of 'baruch sheptarani' which talks about being released from punishment for the child. If the child can't commit a sin, there should also be no punishment (for either the child or the parent) to be released from.

Comment: Are you just talking about ben adam lemakom? Because of course, a child can do something that is unacceptable in ben adam lechavero, and the parent has to prevent that

Comment: @RabbiKaii It may be unacceptable to you but it isn't prohibited for them to do. Unless you are claiming that children are obligated in mitzvot bein adam lachavero

Comment: @DoubleAA I am claiming that if a child commits a sin against a human being, such as murder, we can't say that "they didn't sin". The premise of the question is that children can't sin, but that seems wrong. Children are not _blamed_ for their sins; their parents are. The only reasonable exception I could fathom might be some source I've never seen that children are not capable of sinning against Hashem (because He forgoes it or something)

Comment: @RabbiKaii Are children obligated to not murder?

Comment: I imagine at least part of it is paying compensation for physical damage, and probably for responsibility of chinuch etc

Comment: @DoubleAA I am trying to work out if I am being very dumb (highly likely) or if the question could use more rigor. "Sin", "obligation", "responsibility", "punishment" are all getting conflated here or could use definition

Comment: user9806 are you just saying that if a child is not obligated in mitzvot, then what does "shepartani me'onesh" mean? Patur from what?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4857/mitzvot-for-ketanim

Comment: @RabbiKaii I suppose it's actually a two part question: 1. Can children ever sin (anything - including murder,etc.) since they're not obligated in mitzvos 2. If they can't sin, then what punishment (i.e. for what) is the parent being released from when they come of age

Comment: 1 would be a dupe of @rosends link I think. I still don't get 2. Maybe better phrased positively i.e. "what is a parent responsible for during the time when their children are ketanim who are not obligated in mitzvot"?

Comment: I edited the question a bit to be more clear about 2. Re 1, true, it does overlap with the question in @rosends link, but a) that question is pretty old by now and may use more answers b) something emerging here in sharper relief, namely 'is there _any_ sin, including big ones, that a child can commit?'  seems interesting enough to be asked again/separately

Comment: It seems to me that a child simply isn’t obligated to do any mitzvot meaning mitzvot Aseh, but by mitzvot lo taaseh he can be punished for those but the punishment goes to the parent